# Swift Sprite disappears when in contact with Bullet

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have this spaceshooter game where it spawns enemy ships randomly. once the player reaches 30, it would spawn a "Boss" Sprite. In the original App, I have it set up to where the boss would appear and only move left and right because I ran into an issue with the sprite disappearing once it collided with the bullet.

I do not have it set up to where if both contacts were made, it would remove the Boss from parent.

I tried to close in on the problem by copying the app and deleting everything besides the player and the boss sprite.

The sprite disappears when physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self is set so it is a collision issue.

Could this be a bug with the xcode?

It is not the image itself because i took out the images and i am using just the placeholder image (big red X) saying that no image of that name was found.

Here is a gif of what it looks like
[bullet hitting boss](http://g.recordit.co/8ucvkrwR4Z.gif)

the left side of the screen shows the bullets being shot from bottom to top
the image coming from right to left is the boss sprite

Here is my gamescene.swift

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

struct PhysicsCatagory {
    static let Enemy : UInt32 = 1 //000000000000000000000000000001
    static let Bullet : UInt32 = 0b1 //00000000000000000000000000010
    static let Player : UInt32 = 4 //00000000000000000000000000100
    static let tj: UInt32  = 0b10

}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var Highscore = Int()
    var Score = Int()
    var BossCounter = Int()
    var TJBossHIT = Int()

    var Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player")
    var Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy.png")
    var TJ = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tjBoss9.png")
    var Fake = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tjBoss.png")
    var ScoreLbl = UILabel()

    let HealthBarWidth: CGFloat = 100
    let HealthBarHeight: CGFloat = 40
    var TJHealth = 20

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


        Score = 0

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
         // self.scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
         self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: 640, height: 1136)
        self.scene?.zPosition = 0
        Player.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 5)
        Player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Player.size)
        Player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
        Player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Enemy
        Player.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
          var Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnBullets"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)






          let enemy1SpawnDelay = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)



        runAction(
            SKAction.sequence([
                enemy1SpawnDelay,
                SKAction.runBlock({self.SpawnTJ()}),
                SKAction.waitForDuration(0.4)]) , withKey: "SpawnStop")


    }



    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {


            var firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
            var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB
            //TJ Section for Coliision with bullets
            if (((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.tj) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet)) ||
                ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.tj))){

                    // CollisionWithTJBoss(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode), Bullet: (secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
                    CollisionWithTJBoss(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, TJ: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

        }
    }

    func CollisionWithBullet(Enemy: SKSpriteNode, Bullet:SKSpriteNode){
        Enemy.removeFromParent()
        Bullet.removeFromParent()
        Score++


        ScoreLbl.text = "\(Score)"
        print(Score)
    }
    func SpawnTJ() {

        TJ.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: TJ.size)
        TJ.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.tj
        TJ.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bullet


        TJ.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        TJ.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        TJ.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false


        TJ.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height + 30)
        TJ.zPosition = 0.1

        //TJ.zPosition = 0
        let moveDown = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height / 2, duration: 5.0)

        let moveRight = SKAction.moveByX(200, y: 0, duration: 2.0)
        let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-200, y: 0, duration: 3.0)

        let reverseMoveRight = moveRight.reversedAction()
        let reverseMoveLeft = moveLeft.reversedAction()

        let sequence1 = SKAction.sequence([moveRight, reverseMoveRight, moveLeft, reverseMoveLeft])
        // let sequence1 = SKAction.sequence([moveLeft, reverseMoveLeft, moveRight, reverseMoveRight])
        // let endlessAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence)



        TJ.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveDown]))
        TJ.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence1), withKey: "TJBossEnd")

        self.addChild(TJ)

    }

        func CollisionWithTJBoss (Bullet: SKSpriteNode, TJ:SKSpriteNode)
    {
        Bullet.removeFromParent()
        TJBossHIT++
        NSLog("Hit")
        print(TJBossHIT)


    }

    func SpawnBullets(){

        let Bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bullets")
        Bullet.zPosition = -2
        Bullet.position = CGPointMake(Player.position.x, Player.position.y)

        let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 15, duration: 0.8)
        let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        Bullet.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))

        Bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Bullet.size)
        Bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bullet
        Bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Enemy
       // Bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bullet
        Bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.tj

        Bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        self.addChild(Bullet)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            Player.position.x = location.x

        }

        }
        override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

            for touch: AnyObject in touches {
                let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

                Player.position.x = location.x

            }

        }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bullets and your enemies have the same `categoryBitMAsk` value of 1:

```
static let Enemy : UInt32 = 1 //000000000000000000000000000001
static let Bullet : UInt32 = 0b1 //00000000000000000000000000010
```

so any tests for Enemy will also match Bullet and vice-versa.

Also, in your didBeginContact, you deal with the collision by calling another function as follows:

```
CollisionWithTJBoss(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, TJ: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
```

and `CollisionWithTJBoss` is defined as :

```
func CollisionWithTJBoss (Bullet: SKSpriteNode, TJ:SKSpriteNode)
```

but you haven't done anything to guarantee the firstBody is the bullet and secondBody is TJ (the boss). So when you do  `Bullet.removeFromParent()` in `CollisionWithTJBoss` I think that the sprite you think is the bullet i.e. firstBody is actually TJ.

For debugging purposes, give your sprites names and in `didBeginContact` do:

```
print("First body is \(firstBody.node.name) and second body is \(secondBody.node.name)")
```

To remove a specific sprite, when you don't if it's firstBody or secondBody, use the following:

```
        let bulletNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node!
        bulletNode.removeFromParent()
```

which guarantees that bulletNode is the bullet (if your categoryBitMasks are set correctly).

You might find it less confusing to restructure your `didBeginContact` as follows:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch contactMask {
    // TJ and Bullet have contacted
    case PhysicsCatagory.tj | PhysicsCatagory.Bullet :
        let bulletNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node!
        bulletNode.removeFromParent()
        TJBossHIT -= 1    // ++ is deprecated
        NSLog("Boss and Bullet have Hit")
        print(TJBossHIT)

    default :
        //Some other contact has occurred
        print("Some other contact")
    }
}
```

You can just add as many `PhysicsCategory.TJ | PhysicsCategory.Bullet` cases as you need for all the contacts that you have to take action for in your game. Code each potential contact individually and you won't loose yourself in if...then...else

Comment: It doesnt work. I had it to 1,2,3,4 for each but I changed them at the last second to see any effect.

Comment: I removed the ContacttestBitmask from bullet to where it shouldnt test to see if collision was made between bullet and TJ and it still makes the Boss Sprite Disappear

Comment: Later it will count the contact as a Hit and it will raise the hit counter.

Comment: I had it counting the hits and just removing the bullet from parent. So its Invincible for now. I wanted to test and see if the image did come down after i reached a certain Score. But I came across the image disappearing

Comment: So the bullet is supposed to be removed, not the boss sprite?

Comment: i removed the CollisionWithTJBoss's Bullet.removeParent and the image doesnt disappear anymore. It does get pushed by the bullet. So the issue is when the bullet touches the boss sprite and when the bullet is getting removed from parent

Comment: That may actually be the problem . How would  I make sure that the first body will always be Bullet and second body will be TJ?  Thank you for viewing my code

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. The part in the switch statement says " removeFromParent(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask" gives me an error saying that UInt 32 has no member  BodyA

Comment: Yes - sorry about that. I was typing from memory. I've corrected the answer. Also, you've spelt 'category' wrong in your PhysicsCategory struct (you;ve put PhysicsCatagory) 

Comment: That did the trick ! Thank you so much. Been at this for days. I will be sure to double check my code for little issues like this.

Comment: Glad I could help - feel free to up vote my answer  Is it working as it should now?